# Whats better in the job market, and what has a better future: Java or C#?

Tags: c#, java

I've learned a lot of programming language, and I think that Java or C# are most likely the best for getting a job, but I was wondering if I am correct in thinking this, or are there other popular languages I should know about?

Comment: Questions like this are better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the trends, Java is slowly losing popularity whilst C# is increasing in popularity:

http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

The Oracle buyout and subsequent astonishing mismanagement of Sun might have an impact on Java's future prospects, but there will always be Java jobs.  You can still get jobs working on 30 year old COBOL projects; there's too much Java code around for it to disappear any time soon.